# Two Projects Referencing the same podfile

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

So I have one big project with two smaller swift projects inside of it like so.[image]

The code for my PodFile that you see highlighted looks like this

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Eventful' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Auth’
    pod 'Firebase/Database’
    pod 'Firebase/Storage’
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging’
    pod 'BPStatusBarAlert'
    pod ’SwiftyJSON’
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'AlamofireImage'
    pod 'AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator'
    pod ‘SVProgressHUD’
    pod "SwiftyCam"
    pod ‘TextFieldEffects’
    pod 'SwiftLocation'
    pod 'EZSwipeController'
    pod 'IGListKit', :git => 'https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit.git', :branch => 'master'
    pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'FaceAware'
    pod "Hero"    
    # Pods for Eventful

end



target 'DynamoCollectionView' do
    # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    use_frameworks!
    pod "Hero"
    # Pods for Eventful

end
```

It says it can not find the project how would I make this podfile support both of these projects mind you the other one is not a workspace. I did make a workspace but I am not sure how to switch them if that would be the solution...But yeah I basically need to make this podfile work for both projects.

Comment: [This](https://www.natashatherobot.com/cocoapods-installing-same-pod-multiple-targets/) will do for you if you need multiple target, it should work for multiple project inside one workspace

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov that's not true, CocoaPods can work with any number of projects, provided they are accessible from the Podfile location.

Comment: @Cristik Hmm. Perhaps you are right.

Comment: @Ron https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4585